# html5で画像をペーストできるエリアを作りたい

Tags: javascript, html5

html5で、テキストエリアに画像をペーストできる枠を作ることはできますか？
iPhoneのメモ帳には画像をペーストできますが、あのようなイメージです

Comment: 「テキストエリア」とは`<textarea>`のことでしょうか。また「ペースト」とはどういう動作でしょうか。iphoneも持っていないので不明ですが、とりあえずエディタ画面をつくって画像を張り付けられるように、と解釈して、textareaではなく`<div contenteditable="true" />`な要素にいろいろ画像を挿入する[サンプル](https://jsfiddle.net/2dmsq052/)を作ってみました。私の環境（firefox 46.0.1）では、別のタブで開いたwebページの画像やローカルの画像をドラッグ&ドロップすることで挿入もできました。試してみてください。[参考](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793090)

Comment: サンプルわざわざお作りいただき感謝いたします。また説明不足につき申し訳ありません。URLやパスを指定して読み込ませるのではなくて、ユーザーのコピー操作でクリップボードに追加された画像をそのままペーストできるようにしたいのです。iPhoneをお使いになったことがないようなので別の例を出しますと、Microsoft Ofiice のExcelにはクリップボードからそのまま画像をペーストできますが、あのようなイメージです。

Comment: MacのSafariやCromeでは上記できませんでしたが、iPhoneのSafariでサンプルにアクセスして試したところ、画像のペーストはできました。しかし貼った画像の縦横比がかわってしまうのですが、コードで何か指定していますでしょうか？

Comment: あ、cssの方で #editor img のサイズを指定していますね。自己解決すみません。またわからないことが出てきましたら改めて質問させていただきます。誠にありがとうございました。